# Collision detection for Monotouch

Tags: 2d, physics, monotouch

What I want to have for my Monotouch 2D projects:
simple collision detection and collision polygons working with UIViews

Sounds simple, isn't it? I've evaluated a lot of engines available on the market, but none of them gives me this simplicity without unnecessary overrun in my projects.

Box2D, monogame/farseer or Cocos2d seems to be good enough, but I don't really want to drag all that functionality to have 2 simple algs.

The question is: is there anything like this out there, or should I go and implement all this myslef?

Comment: How about stealing just what you need from an open source engine like monogame?

Comment: I wouldn't use term 'steal' though :) it seems like it is the only option I have to adapt some parts of open source engines to work in the way I need...

Comment: "Good programmers write good code. Great programmers steal great code"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Chipmunk bindings I wrote to manage UIViews collisions. I document that in this [post](http://blog.reblochon.org/2013/02/our-business-app-doesnt-need-your-game.html). The bindings can be compiled with or without cocos2d. The latest version of the code is [here](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/pull/89)

Comment: Thank you! that's really great article! I've never thought that it is possible and that easy to make this kinda smart labels using physics engine!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:
it seems to be possible to use monotouch/monogame version of Farseer Engine without monogame itself. So, couple of changes to the code and this article
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/05/physics-101-uikit-app-with-box2d-for-gravity/
will get me to the point I have everything I need plus some extras :)

problem seems to be solved!